# I am trying to create a splash screen in my project but this code is not working. it just shows the splash screen forever

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**I am trying to create a splash screen in my project but this code is not working. it just shows the splash screen forever. it doesn't switch to the home screen. Any help? (I want to create an app that starts with a splash screen but i don't want this splash screen to be a photo)**

````
import 'dart:async';
void main() {
  runApp( splash(),);
}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() => _splashState();
}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class _splashState extends State<splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 5),
            () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => home(),),),);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
       body: Center(child: Text("Splash Screen"),)
      ),
    );
  }
}
class home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class _homeState extends State<home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your MaterialApp from your splash

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(),);
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Splash(),
    );
  }
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
          () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Home(),),),);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text("Splash Screen"),)
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```